# Navigating UWP - navigateuri: msnweather

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, navigation

I want to know if there is a way to navigate to built in windows weather app(MSN weather), but also send through a location for it to load the weather data for?

This is what I have so far. Just need to send data to the app.

```
<HyperlinkButton Margin="25,25,0,0" NavigateUri="msnweather: ">Click here for weather</HyperlinkButton>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add some code...what you tried..

Comment: sorry just added

Comment: All the known schemes and documentation for built-in apps is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-default-app), but I don't see the weather app.  You might want to submit a content request at the bottom of that page and ask about the msnweather: protocol.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to poke the docs team and they've got a Pull Request going to update the docs [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windows-uwp/pull/939).

Hopefully, it'll be live soon on the main [doc page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-default-app) for this topic.

If you look at the PR, you can see the urischeme for the weather app is to use the latitude and longitude:

```
msnweather://forecast?la=47.67858&lo=-122.1316
```

This will load the weather app and show the weather for `Redmond, WA`.